# php Handling many orders in OOP

Tags: php, oop, collections

Trying to learn OOP (finally) but struggle with handling more than one item such as a Customers orders, an Orders order rows, etc. As I understand OOP I should not create an object within an object, I should not access data directly, only via setters and getters, I should not duplicate methods and I should keep class integrity/encapsulate.

Ex: Simple Order class and no problem to get, add, insert order. For handling many orders I have tried different approaches.

1) The easiest was to have a method in Order returning all orderid's for the customer and then have a loop in the script creating order objects for each of those orderid's. Not good since it made many calls to the DB. One for each object.

2) Next was to have the same method return all orderdata for all orders for the customer instead and create Order objects in a loop that don't have to get data from database. The problem with this is that it doesn't seem correcct, since I then handle the data in the script directly and not via getters and setters.

3) Next I moved the handling of many orders to its own class. I tried to create a OrderCollection class and look at the collection of orders as an object. Seems there are advantages with ArrayIterator etc when you use it. But I found no way to solve it this way either since I want them all to be Order objects and use methods in Order Class on them.

This seems such a basic thing and I am very surprised that spending several days searching and reading tutorials and forums have given absolutely nothing.
So please point me in the right direction on how to handle it in OOP when it is more than one item. I guess it is also this time me thinking in the totally wrong direction, but please be gentle, I am new to this.

Script:

```
// test data
$customerid = 1001;
$orderid = 2233;

// db
$dbh = new DB();

// This works fine
// Order
$order = new Order($dbh);
$order-set_orderid($orderid);
$order->select_order();
echo "orderdate: ".$order-get_date();

// This is were I have problems
// Orders
$customerorders = new OrderCollection($dbh);
$customerorders->select_all_orders_for_customerid($customerid);

// now I can iterate through the customerorders:
foreach ($customerorders as $orderrow)
{
    echo $orderrow->orderid . ", ";
    echo $orderrow->orderdate . ", ";
    echo $orderrow->ordervalue."<br />";
}
// but this seems not correct since I am now handling the data directly from database and not via getters
// also I cant use any other Order method on these since they are not Order objects
```

Order Class

```
    class Order
{
    private $order;
    private $orderdate;
    private $ordervalue;
    private $db;
    public function __construct($db_handle)
    {
        $this->db = $db_handle;
    }
    public function select_order()
    {
        try 
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderid=:orderid");
            $stmt->bindParam(':orderid', $this->orderid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $order_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $this->orderdate = $order_row['orderdate'];
            $this->ordervalue = $order_row['ordervalue'];
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    public function select_all_orders_for_customerid()
    {
        // get all orderdata from database for customerid and return an array of orders with all data

    }
    // update, insert, delete methods ... in here

    // getters
    public function get_orderid() { return $this->orderid;  }
    public function get_sorderdate() {  return $this->orderdate;    }
    public function get_ordervalue() {  return $this->ordervalue;   }
    // setters
    public function set_orderid($new_servid) { $this->orderid = $new_orderid; }
    public function set_orderdate($new_orderdate) { $this->orderdate = $new_orderdate; }
    public function set_ordervalue($new_ordervalue) { $this->ordervalue = $new_ordervalue; }
}
```

Order  Collection Class

```
class OrderCollection implements IteratorAggregate
{
    private $collection = array();
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db_handle)
    {
        $this->db = $db_handle;
    }

    public function select_all_orders_for_customerid($customerid)
    {
        try 
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM order WHERE customerid=:customerid");
            $stmt->bindParam(':customerid', $this->customerid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->collection = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->collection);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use error checking http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and then look/visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html as to why your code is failing or a very big contributor. I.e.: `order`.

Comment: @fred  Thank you for your comment, but error checking has nothing to do with what I am asking about. Sorry if I am not making myself clear. I am trying to understand the structure/logics for OOP when having more than one item/order/customer or other object.  I took out most of the error handling in order to make the classes small when showing them here.

Comment: ok, so not taking care of your table isn't a factor then. I see.

Comment: Learning about OOP via php is going to be hard due to the procedural history of the language (like 90% of the code i see under the php tag on here is very poorly written, procedural php), but building an ORM is 100% **NOT** a good beginner task! If you dont fancy learning a stricter OOP language as a primer (kind of a joke, but certainly usefull), then go pick a popular modern framework and learn to use that - you should pick up OOP practices as you go. Alternatively start with a far more simple task

Comment: @Steve. Thanks for the comment. I have no problem using another language in order to learn OOP. What language do you propose? I am an old procedural programmer and "my languages" are assempler, pl/1, cobol, and a few other. I have used php for many years but only procedural style.

Comment: @Frank. You misunderstand me. What I try to say is that my question is about the structure of OOP.  Sorry if the code was a bad example for my question. I am new here and maybe I am asking my question in the wrong way.

Comment: Well, as a purely personal choice, i learned with c#. The language is well structured, and more importantly for me (then) as a beginner, there is a limited set of frameworks in use, predominantly ones created by the language creators (microsoft), and a single (excellent, free) IDE (visual studio) So pretty much every tutorial you find will have similar code, unlike for example Java, which is also well structured, and arguably more used, but tutorials are fractured over a thousand different frameworks and tools.

Comment: Even now, if i have a doubt about higher level OOP concepts (dependency injection, design patterns etc) i will always google "c# {search term}" or Java {searchterm} then translate the idea to php, rather than sift through the often misleading results for "php {searchterm}"!

Comment: That said, its probably not at all practical to learn a new language if you are trying to get something done in php right now. Instead try as i suggested and learn a decent modern php framework. Laravel is currently very popular. Its not the easiest to set up, and is in my opinion over engineered in many places, but it has a great community and good tutorials available